# Gin-Gonic trouble understanding imports

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm trying out Gin-Gonic for the first time but I'm having problems understanding how to properly structure my application in a way that will be easier to maintain going forward.

A lot of the tutorials I have looked at demonstrate setting up all the applications routes within `func main`, but that would get unwieldy quickly. I'd like to be able to structure it something akin to traditional `MVC`, something similar to `Revel` for example.

My structure looks something like this so far:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
├── routes
│   └── routes.go
└── templates
    ├── footer.html
    ├── header.html
    └── index.html

2 directories, 7 files
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    initializeRoutes()
    router.Run()
}
```

routes.go

```
package routes

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func initializeRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    router.GET("/", showIndexPage)
}

func showIndexPage(c *gin.Context) {
    c.String(200, "OK")
}
```

When I run `go run main.go` I get th ebelow error, as expected without the import.

```
> go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:10:2: undefined: initializeRoutes
```

But when I try to import `routes/routes.go` it is never recognised and when I save import is removed.

I have tried the following but I cannot get this import to be recognised.

```
./routes
github.com/my-repo/ginApp/routes
```

What am I missing here in order to get this to work?

Comment: Do not use go run. Use go build. Use modules. Read How to write Go Code.

Comment: https://go.dev/tour/basics/3

Comment: @Volker, this is part of the problem. I can't save the code. Saving it removes the import because, I assume, it's not used in the code or not seen to be

Answer (score 0):

So it had nothing to do with whether I was using `build` or `run`. The issue as mentioned in a link in one of the comments was to do with the naming convention I was using.

[Go Docs - Exported Names](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3)

```
In Go, a name is exported if it begins with a capital letter. For example, Pizza is an exported name, as is Pi, which is exported from the math package.

pizza and pi do not start with a capital letter, so they are not exported.
```

I just changed `initializeRoutes` to `InitializeRoutes` and I was able to access this function from my main package via `routes.InitializeRoutes()`.